# What is cuDNN implementation of rnn cells in Tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, cudnn

To create `RNN` cells, there are classes like `GRUCell` and `LSTMCell` which can be used later to create `RNN` layers.
And also there are 2 other classes as `CudnnGRU` and `CudnnLSTM` which can be directly used to create `RNN` layers.

In the documentation they say that the latter classes have `cuDNN` implementation. Why should I use or not use this `cuDNN` implemented classes over classical `RNN` implementations when I'm creating a `RNN` model..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short: cudnnGRU and cudnnLSTM can/ must be used on GPU, normal rnn implementations not. So if you have tensorflow-gpu, cudnn implementation of RNN cells would run faster.

Answer (score 0):

`CuDNNLSTM` and `CuDNNGRU` are the fast implementation backed by `CuDNN`. Both can only be run on the `GPU`, with the TensorFlow backend. The `cuDNN` is a GPU-accelerated library of primitives for deep neural networks.

The `cuDNN` provides highly tuned implementations for standard routines such as forward and backward convolution, pooling, normalization, and activation layers. `cuDNN` is part of the NVIDIA Deep Learning SDK.

The [cuDNN](https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn)  highlights include:

1. Up to 3x faster training of ResNet-50 and GNMT on Tesla V100 vs.
   Tesla P100
2. Improved NHWC support for pooling and strided convolution
3. Get Improved performance for common workloads such as ResNet50 and SSD as batchnorm now supports NHWC data layout with an added option
               to fuse batchnorm with Add and ReLu operations